# I want to add dynamic class

Tags: jquery, html, css

Hi I have 100 divs in a page. So I want to add 5 class to dynamically. Let's say .class-1, .class-2, .class -3, .class-4, .class-5 and these 5 classes need to be repated for those 100 divs. How can I achieve dynamically.  As im new to here, please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Why do you need this? The point of `class` attributes is to group elements, not to index them individually. 99% of the time a better approach is to group the elements then traverse the DOM around them as needed when they fire an event.

Comment: you need to apply class on all divs on your page

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I think OP is asking for them to be grouped (ie. `20xdiv.class-1`, `20xdiv.class-2` etc.)

Comment: My point remains, have a `.item-group` class containing `.item` elements and traverse as needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/ilmkamil/SpTVL/2/)?

**html**

```
<div id="menu">
    <ul>
        <li>one</li>
        <li>two</li>
        <li>three</li>
        <li>four</li>
        <li>five</li>
        <li>six</li>
        <li>seven</li>
        <li>eight</li>
        <li>nine</li>
        <li>ten</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**jquery**

```
var i = 0;
var count = 5;
$("#menu ul li").each(function () {
    if (i < count) {
        i++
    } else {
        i = 1;
    }
    $(this).addClass("item-" + (i));
});
```

Comment: Yes, but instead of li, I will use it for div. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tested this, but this should do the trick.

```
$.each("div", function( index, value ) {
   var mod = (index % 5) + 1;
   $(this).addClass('class-' + mod);
});
```

Comment: This works only considering there are only 100 divs and no other 'div' tag anywhere else..

Comment: That is true. It will only work in this case, but the code can be adapted for selecting the right div's.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a function to `addClass()`, then just use the current `index` with the modulus operator to work out the correct number to assign:

```
$('div').addClass(function(index, currentClass) {
  return 'class-' + (index % 5 + 1);
});
```

#### [Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Entp5/6/)

Answer (score 0):

Pure JS Version:

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SpTVL/4/)

```
var i = 0,
    count = 5,
    elem = document.getElementsByTagName("li");

for(a = 0; a < elem.length; a++)
{
    if (i < count) {
        i++
    } else {
        i = 1;
    }        
    elem[a].className = "item-"+i;
}
```